# Websites to share fiction containing extreme content?

Tags: publishing, websites, erotica

I’m writing a work of fiction containing extreme and sometimes gratuitous instances of gore, sexual violence and abuse. (I believe my work has artistic and literary merits, and the aforementioned subjects contribute to that intent, but that’s besides the point. I will not compromise.)

Are there websites that allow me to share writing of this sort?

Objective criteria for acceptable websites:

- The website should allow submission containing the aforementioned content.
- The website should allow such submissions to be viewed by other users or visitors.
- The website should explicitly aimed towards writing-sharing. (As opposed to being primarily pornographic in purpose, for instance)
- If possible, the website should have a large user-base and be accessible through normal means (as opposed to accessed by deep-net, for example.)

Comment: I'm not sure this isn't opinion-based (though I'm not sure enough that it *is* that I'm going to mod-hammer the question closed), but besides that, **"share" for what purpose?** Are you looking for some place to just put it up so that people are able to access it, or are you looking for an established ebook publishing platform, or are you looking for literary critique, or what?

Comment: This question is considered "broad" because it has the potential to have many correct answers, not one definitive answer, therefore it is off-topic on StackExchange as a whole.  If there are such websites, a quick Google search can provide a list of potential sites for you to use.

Comment: @aCVn I do not believe this is opinion-based. There exist objective criteria for what website can be accepted as correct answers. Question will be updated.

Comment: @ChrisRogers If there were many correct answers, I wouldn't be asking a question here. Searching "censorship-free writing sharing website" and similar phrases do not yield satisfying results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.asstr.org/ the Alt Sex Stories Text Repository accepts erotic stories of any type or content. It has many such stories on file, dating back many years. It is most ly oriented to disply of stories, not to critical comment from readers. Caution, image on the opening page is Not-safe-for-work.

The ASSTR FAQ, under "Inappropriate Material" says:

> One of ASSTR's founding principles is free speech, and as a result of this we welcome with open arms just about any kind of erotic literature that someone is willing to take the time to write. With this in mind, anyone with anything less than a completely open mind is sure to find something that would get their stomach churning or their temper flamed.
>
> One thing to keep in mind is that most, if not all, stories at ASSTR are fictional. While something terrible, gross, and/or offensive may be described, remember that in all likelihood the event(s) never occurred in real life and in most cases the author is in no way advocating anyone taking part in such activities. Rather, some people enjoy writing about such events, and others enjoy reading them. We can't offer any further explanation than this.
>
> As for the legality of some of the more offensive works at ASSTR, particularly those containing underage characters, the US Supreme Court ruled on April 16, 2002 that adult material depicting minors but that was not made through the use of any actual minor is protected free speech. The ruling was against the Child Pornography Prevention Act of 1996 (CPPA) and the entire ruling is available via Findlaw.com.

https://www.literotica.com/ is a somewhat similar site that includes a discussion board with a story feedback section A bit more restrictive on what content is accepted (for example no under-18 characters in a sexual relationship). Cover image is less prominent, but also not-safe-for-work.

Comment: I am researching the site policies of https://www.asstr.org/ at this moment, but I know for a fact that https://www.literotica.com/ prohibits sexual violence, and does so using a very inconsistent assessment method.

Comment: @user289661 : I think you will find that asstr has an "anything goes" policy, as long is it is text, not an image. They have a significant BDSM sub-section, and specifically mention that stories of childhood abuse are accepted.